# Ошибка при запуске бота Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py

Запуска самый первый код который предлагает официальная документация. Питон ломается.

```
 File "C:\python_program\Bots\BotDS\botds.py", line 1, in <module>
   import discord
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
   from .client import Client
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
   import aiohttp
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   from .client import (
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 35, in <module>
   from . import hdrs, http, payload
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http.py", line 7, in <module>
   from .http_parser import (
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
   from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 48, in <module>
   from typing_extensions import Protocol
 File "C:\python_program\venv\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py", line 2084, in <module>
   def TypeAlias(self, parameters):
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'
```

Вот сам код:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run('токн')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прописать

> pip install -U discord.py
> А так скажи свою версию python.